# Movie/GIF background iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview, uber-api

If you look at the Uber app on iOS, you will notice that the Sign In/Register screen has a short movie clip as the background. I am trying to replicate that in my own iOS app. Right now I am following [this](https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-make-an-awesome-video-background-view-objective-c-swift-318e1d71d0a2) tutorial to use a `UIWebView` to make a GIF the background. Now, I want to use a looping `.mov` or other movie file format instead of a looping gif. Are there any APIs that can help me replicate this?

EDIT:

So I unzipped the Uber.ipa file and it turns out their welcome video is of `.mp4` format if this is helpful information.

Comment: take a look at AVPlayer

Comment: Is there a difference between AVPlayer and MPMoviePlayer?

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController is a VC And internally it uses AVPlayer. But since you need custom controls for the video overlay you have to use AVPlayer and set your view with AVPlayerLayer with no control overlay

Comment: Thanks Vig. Also, Uber's welcome video is 608x1080 which is obviously smaller than the iPhone 6+ resolution. Does AVPlayer scale appropriately? I want to make sure that auto layout scales the video properly cross-iPhone.

Comment: Take a look at this, you can scale your video accordingly https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Video_Gravity

Comment: Appreciate the help Vig, thank you.

Comment: Posted an answer check that as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func playVideo() {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType:"mp4")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        if let player = moviePlayer {
            player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
            player.controlStyle = .None
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.scalingMode = .AspectFit
            self.view.addSubview(player.view)
        }
    }
```

After few comments I looked on to `MPMoviePlayerController` and it has options to disable the controls. Learnt something :) this method will help you play a .mp4 as you mentioned.